# Drag drop clone with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, resizable

I'm beginer to js and programing and I need little help if someone can help me with my code...

I create some "simple trip planner" but I need to clone class `.draggable` on table but also need to work just like here:http://jsbin.com/erofot/17 , so only to add a clone and to work in the same way

So after dragging, div must be again resizable, draggable , so just on example.

How to do that?

I was try with helper:clone but isnt work.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

the code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: 'invalid', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're cloning the element then you need to instantiate draggable, resizable, etc. again on drop:

```
$("#drop_here td").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find("p").html("Dropped!");
        var drg = ui.draggable.clone()
        drg.resizable();
        drg.draggable({revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
        $(this).append(drg);
    }
});
```

Here's updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erofot/84/edit).

Comment: @MarkWest Hi Mark. I have updated the answer and also added a link to jsbin updated.

Comment: No, its not the problem. What I exactly need: Just I need to clone div s from sidebar, so when I put div into table there I need to be only raggable and resizable, not clonable... and also to can clone div from sidebar multiple times not just once

Comment: So I need to work just like in my example: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17, only to add cloneable function from sidebar...